# I can't figure out how to link msi.lib to my Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer

I'm trying to write a simple application that will enumerate all the ProductCodes installed on my machine.

I've started a new project in Visual Studio 2013, but whenever I build I get the error:
**"LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MsiEnumProductsExA@32 referenced in function _main"**

I've been trying to figure out how to add msi.lib to my project include path, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
#define _WIN32_MSI 300

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Msi.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Get a list of all installed MSIs
    DWORD index = 0;
    TCHAR currentProductCode[40] = {0};
    unsigned int result = ERROR_SUCCESS;

   // Open an MSI handle
   while (ERROR_SUCCESS == result) {
      result = MsiEnumProductsEx(NULL, "s-1-1-0",
                                 MSIINSTALLCONTEXT_USERMANAGED | MSIINSTALLCONTEXT_USERUNMANAGED | MSIINSTALLCONTEXT_MACHINE,
                                 index, currentProductCode, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
         cout << "current ProductCode: " << currentProductCode;
      }
      index++;
   }

    return 0;
}
```

I've been trying to update the project's Property Pages by adding the path to the msi.lib to the "Library Directories" property, but that doesn't seem to work:
[image: Property Page Screenshot]

This is like Visual Studio 101, what am I missing?!

Comment: Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional dependencies. Just add msi.lib to the list there.

Comment: `msi.lib` should be missing. Add it and compile again if that works,

Comment: Are you sure you've got a Windows SDK installed? That's the best place to get it from.

Comment: Yep, I had the SDK installed. Thanks for the comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Configuration Properties>Linker>Input

Add msi.lib in Additional Dependencies Thats it! Make sure you are using same calling conversion, which used to built the lib. i.e either stdcall or cdecl.